# create array of array of object in javascript to get the desired result

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arrayofarrays

Need a specific array structure.

```
arr = [];
arr1 = {'a':12,'b':11};
arr2 = {'c':12,'d':12};
arr.push(arr1);
arr.push(arr2);`
```

with this i got the result

```
(2) [Object, Object]
0:
{
 a:12,
 b:11
}
1:
{
 c:12,
 d:12
}
```

But I need this response

```
[{'a':12,'b':11},{'c':12,'d':12}]
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, console.log(arr) gives the response you expect.

Comment: Those are two notations mean the same thing. How are you trying to use the response?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You want an array with two objects. One with properties `a` and `b`. The other with properties `c` and `d`. That's what you're getting.

Comment: 0: and 1: are simply your console print telling you the index of those elements.

Comment: As with many  things in life, it's more important what's inside of `arr` (the value of `arr`), not what it *appears* to be from the outside (how the console displays the value). What you have is exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All current browsers have native JSON support built in. So as long as you're not dealing with prehistoric browsers like IE6/7 you can do it just as easily as that:

```
JSON.stringify(arr); //"[{"a":12,"b":11},{"c":12,"d":12}]"
```

Comment: They aren't looking for JSON. Their expected response isn't even valid JSON.

Comment: What makes you think the OP wants JSON?

Comment: I don't think the OP wants a string, but then I don't think the OP knows what they want...

Comment: @ErickLangfordXenes "How is this different?" The quotation marks. Single quotes are not valid JSON. It also seems highly unlikely that they want a string at all.